# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Currently I am getting an error when attempting to build my SQL table the error is stated above in the title "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" I do not understand why it is throwing this however the code itself seems ok...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceReference1.ControlPumpsClient WCFSQL = new SQLserver.ServiceReference1.ControlPumpsClient();
        string[] SQLData = new string[6];
        while (WCFSQL.getData()[0] == null) { }

        if (WCFSQL.getData()[0] != null)
        {
            SQLData = WCFSQL.getData();
        }


        SQLiteConnection myConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data source=test.db; Version=3;");
        myConnection.Open();
        /// If this is not the first time the program has run, 
        /// the table 'cars' will already exist, so we will remove it
        SQLiteCommand tableDropCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
        tableDropCommand.CommandText = "drop table Records";
        try
        {
            tableDropCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex) // We expect this if the table is not present
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table 'Records' does  not exist");
        }

        /// Now create a table called 'records'
        SQLiteCommand tableCreateCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
        tableCreateCommand.CommandText = "create table Records (ID int, FuelType varchar(10), Price float, TankVolume int)";
        tableCreateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        /// Now insert some data.
        /// First, create a generalised insert command
        SQLiteCommand insertCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
        insertCommand.CommandText = "insert into Records (ID, FuelType, Price, TankVolumes) values (@id, @fueltype, @price, @volume)";
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id"));
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@fueltype"));
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@price"));
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@tankvolume"));
        addSQL(insertCommand, int.Parse(SQLData[0]), SQLData[1], float.Parse(SQLData[2]), double.Parse(SQLData[3]));

        /// Now, create a comand to read from the database;
        SQLiteCommand listAllRecordsCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
        listAllRecordsCommand.CommandText = "select * from Records";
        SQLiteDataReader reader = listAllRecordsCommand.ExecuteReader();

        /// Iterate over the results and print them
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(reader["ID"] + ",");
            sb.Append(reader["FuelType"] + ",");
            sb.Append(reader["Price"] + ",");
            sb.Append(reader["Volumes"] + ",");
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }

        myConnection.Close();

        /// Wait for a keypress
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void addSQL(SQLiteCommand insertCommand, int pumpID, string fuel, float price, double volume){
         /// Now, set the values for the insert command and add two records
        insertCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = pumpID;
        insertCommand.Parameters["@fueltype"].Value = fuel;
        insertCommand.Parameters["@price"].Value = price;
        insertCommand.Parameters["@volume"].Value = volume;
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

The error occurs on this line which is highlighted in yellow

```
insertCommand.Parameters["@volume"].Value = volume;
```

Comment: you have spelled it as @tankvolume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a parameter named `"@tankvolume"`, but when you add values to the parameter collection you try to use a parameter named `"@volume"`. This parameter doesn't exist and thus you get the exception. Just use the correct name and the error will disappear.

Or you could just use the AddWithValue method

```
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(SQLData[0]));
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fueltype",SQLData[1]));
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Convert.ToSingle(SQLData[2]));
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tankvolume", Convert.ToDouble(SQLData[3]));
```

I will try also to add some error checking on the variable array SQLData, if, for some reason you don't get back four valid values your code will crash again.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SQLiteCommand insertCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
        insertCommand.CommandText = "insert into Records (ID, FuelType, Price, TankVolumes) values (@id, @fueltype, @price, @tankvolume)";
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id"));
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@fueltype"));
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@price"));
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@tankvolume"));
        addSQL(insertCommand, int.Parse(SQLData[0]), SQLData[1], float.Parse(SQLData[2]), double.Parse(SQLData[3]));





public static void addSQL(SQLiteCommand insertCommand, int pumpID, string fuel, float price, double volume){
         /// Now, set the values for the insert command and add two records
        insertCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = pumpID;
        insertCommand.Parameters["@fueltype"].Value = fuel;
        insertCommand.Parameters["@price"].Value = price;
        insertCommand.Parameters["@tankvolume"].Value = volume;
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```